# How can i call a sub_page.php inside a div container of my main_page.php?

Tags: php, html

I need to show the content of one of my sub_page.php inside my main_page.php

At the moment im using an iframe to do that, but i would like to show the sub_page.php inside a div, so it will have a more professional look.

How can i do that?

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />   
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
<div style="text-align:center;"><img src="faq-banner.png" /></div><br />
<div>
<?php include("faq.php"); ?>
</div>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the div, include the php page with simple `include()` command.

```
<div>
<?php include("subpage.php"); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: not working, it keeps trying to load for ever.. I added my page code in first post.

Comment: Your code is not sufficient to understand. Where is the iframe? Where do you want to load the sub page?

Comment: i removed the iframe and replaced it with the div like you informed. i want to load the sub_page in the boddy, after the banner.jpg image.

Comment: @LucasMatos, It should work the way you are doing it. What are the contents of `faq.php`

Comment: well it worked now, but my website sidebar is being shown below the subpage div. Any idea how to make the side bar apears in its original place?

Comment: I need to see the markup. May be it should be floated to appear correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.include.php) statement which will include and evaluate the specified file:

For example:

vars.php

```
<?php
  $color = 'green';
  $fruit = 'apple';
?>
```

test.php

```
<?php
  echo "A $color $fruit"; // A
  include 'vars.php';
  echo "A $color $fruit"; // A green apple
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you're trying to do is:

```
include('sub_page.php');
```

Include this code within the `div` you're trying to display the subpage in.